# Implementing Attatched Objects: Unclear Documentation Example

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I try to understand the documentation section [**Providing Attached Objects for Data Annotations**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#providing-attached-objects-for-data-annotations), or specifically it's example.

If I get the steps right it works like this:

1. Create a Type (`MessageBoardAttatchedType`) which holds the signals and properties of that shall be accessible through the attached property
2. Create a static method that returns an instance of the affore mentioned type in the type, that shall be used as the attached property (`MessageBoard`)
3. Provide the information, that this attached type exists by invoking the macro `QML_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(..., QML_HAS_ATTACHED_PROPERTIES)`

The following questions arrise for me:

*(Minor one): In the documentation we have this code:*

```
static MessageBoard *qmlAttachedProperties(QObject *object)
{
    return new MessageBoardAttachedType(object);
}
```

The return type is `MessageBoard`, but we return a `MessageBoardAttachedType`. How is that made possible? `MessageBoardAttachedType` does not inherrit `MessageBoard` - is that some magic of the macro in **3.**?

**And the main question**:

[**Here**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers) we learn, that attached properties *may*(?) be available just in very specific `Items` - e.g. just in the delegate root for the `XView` attached properties.

In the example it is not mentioned, that I can access the attatched property from a `Message`-object. How is that determined? By returning `null` from the

```
*qmlAttachedProperties(...)
```

if the passed `*object` does not please me (is not a `Message` e.g.)?

Comment: "The return type is `MessageBoard`" no the return type is `MessageBoard*`. Imho it is bad ugly habit to put the `*` next to the method name instead of where it belongs (the return type).

Comment: As you can see here (https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/5.9/src/quick/items/qquicklistview_p.h#L177), the MessageBoard part ist just a typo. The return type should be the attached type.

Comment: As for the Main Question: Try that idea out, it would be my guess too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning a null pointer from `qmlAttachedProperties` will crash the QML engine.
You should always return an instance of an object in `qmlAttachedProperties`.

You could however display a warning when the object being attached doesn't fit your requirements, either in the `qmlAttachedProperties` function or in the constructor of the attached type.

For example that's how it's done for the `StackView` attached type and multiple others.

The [`qmlAttachedProperties` of `StackView`](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/v5.9.1/src/quicktemplates2/qquickstackview.cpp#L319-L322) returns an object inconditionnaly :

```
QQuickStackViewAttached *QQuickStackView::qmlAttachedProperties(QObject *object)
{
    return new QQuickStackViewAttached(object);
}
```

The [constructor of the `StackView` attached type](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/v5.9.1/src/quicktemplates2/qquickstackview.cpp#L1065-L1077) outputs a warning if the attached object is not an `QQuickItem` (checking with `qobject_cast`), and does its magic only if it is.

```
QQuickStackViewAttached::QQuickStackViewAttached(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(*(new QQuickStackViewAttachedPrivate), parent)
{
    Q_D(QQuickStackViewAttached);
    QQuickItem *item = qobject_cast<QQuickItem *>(parent);
    if (item) {
        connect(item, &QQuickItem::visibleChanged, this, &QQuickStackViewAttached::visibleChanged);
        QQuickItemPrivate::get(item)->addItemChangeListener(d, QQuickItemPrivate::Parent);
        d->itemParentChanged(item, item->parentItem());
    } else if (parent) {
        qmlWarning(parent) << "StackView must be attached to an Item";
    }
}
```